# How much data is in pipe(c++)

Tags: c++, pipe

I am trying to guess how much data is in pipe, and I don't want to use `while(read)` because it is blocking until EOF.

Is there any way to do that?

I real I want something like this:

```
i = pipe1.size();
pipe1.read(i);
```

I say again, I don't want to use `while (read)` because it is blocking until EOF.

Comment: It seems like you might need to make the pipe nonblocking, or use [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/select) to know when it has data to read.

Comment: Not exactly. My pipe is getting data for a long time, I want to read data that is in pipe after a while. I am using fork also and can not use thread.

Comment: The idea is good but in my case data enters pipe fast and sequentially.

Comment: `cat /dev/zero | your_application`; how much data is in that pipe?

Answer (score 6):

The amount of data coming from a pipe could be infinite, just a like a stream, there's no concept of `size` in a pipe. if you don't want it to block if there's nothing to read you should set the `O_NONBLOCK` flag when calling `pipe2()`:

```
pipe2(pipefd, O_NONBLOCK);
```

This way when you call `read()` if there's no data it would fail and set `errno` to `EWOULDBLOCK`

```
if (read(fd, ...) < 0) {
   if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
      //no data
   }
   //other errors
}
```

From the man page:

> O_NONBLOCK:  Set  the  O_NONBLOCK  file status flag on the two new open
>   file descriptions.  Using this flag saves extra calls to fcntl(2) to
>   achieve the same result.

You could also use [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) on a blocking pipe to timeout.

Comment: Not exactly. My pipe is getting data for a long time, I want to read data that is in pipe when user asks for it. I am using fork also and can not use thread.

Comment: @HamedJML You can read from the pipe whenever you want. If there is nothing in the pipe you will get the `EWOULDBLOCK` error, and can go back to doing something else. You should be careful when writing to the pipe though, as it has a kind of small buffer and the writer will block when the buffer is full.

Comment: The idea is good but in my case data enters pipe fast and sequentially.

Comment: @HamedJML it doesn't matter the OS buffers the data until you read.

Answer (score 2):

This could help you, however it is unix specific:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>

int pipe_fd; /* your pipe's file descriptor */

......

int nbytes = 0;

//see how much data is waiting in buffer
if ( ioctl(pipe_fd, FIONREAD, &nbytes) < 0 )
{
    std::cout << "error occured: " << errno;
}
else 
{
    std::cout << nbytes << " bytes waiting in buffer";
}
```